# Install Jenkins either without security or with access other then localhost

Tags: jenkins, installation

I have to say, requiring that you enter password to access the setup wizard on jenkins is one of the most frustrating features I've ever encountered!  This works beautifully when you are local to the machine, but if you are setting up a remote server such as a VM, it is INCREDIBLY PAINFUL AND FRUSTRATING!!!  Nothing I've tried disables this feature.  I cannot set security to false, I cannot use a command line browser to enter the generated admin password, and I cannot access the machine remotely until the initial setup wizard has run.

Is there anyway I can get past this bug!?!  It is a bug as the wizard only works if you're local to the machine.

Comment: Why not dockerize it ? Build your own custom image. Every time you want a fresh Jenkins instance, just spin up that container.

Comment: By the way, this is NOT a bug.

Comment: I've tried the Docker version, but the issue there is building docker containers using jenkins in docker.  The missing packages and permission issues are equally as frustrating.  If this isn't a bug, then it's a feature designed to annoy and frustrate your users.

Comment: No. Im simply not buying it. If I hadn't signed an NDA with my company, i'd share with you a repo I built. My docker Image invokes an ansible playbook that customized my Jenkins deployed on Debian. It deploys all custom configs including the root custom config that disables login. It also installs all required plugins. So when my container comes up, I dont need to login and it already contains all I need. So its definitely possible. Your inability to think on how to do does not automatically mean it's a bug on the application side. Hope you sort this out.